# Zend\Feed validation warning with authors

Tags: zend-framework, rss, zend-framework2, feed, google-news

when I create a Feed and I use the `$entry->setAuthor()` method, the generated feed will contain one `<dc:creator>` and one `<author>` for each entry.

If you validate this feed (example: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamempire.it%2Frss-custom%2Fgnews) you notice that there is a warning about the fact that an entry can’t contain both `<dc:creator>` and `<author>`

Besides, I receive a warning from a Google News assistant that tell me they can’t include my rss inside their “Editor’s Pick” box because of it’s not validated with the w3c validator.

So, how to solve this? For example, how to remove the `<dc:creator>` and leave only the `<author>`?

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: I never took the time to write down how to fix this for you, but I answered a similar question. You could check that one if it suits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23006901/434223