# ZF2 how to disable Zend\Feed\Writer\Feed extensions

Tags: rss, zend-framework2, feed

Trying to create a simple rss feed in zend framework2 by using Zend\Feed\Writer\Feed:

```
$feed = new \Zend\Feed\Writer\Feed();

...

$out = $feed->export('rss');
echo $out;
```

And this will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">
  <channel>
    <title>example</title>
    <description>example</description>
    <generator>Zend_Feed_Writer 2 (http://framework.zend.com)</generator>
    <link>http://www.google.com</link>
    <item>
      <title>article1</title>
      <pubDate>Fri, 11 Apr 2014 06:32:53 +0000</pubDate>
      <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>article2</title>
      <pubDate>Fri, 11 Apr 2014 06:32:53 +0000</pubDate>
      <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

My question is:

how to disable xmlns:slash extension `<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a mess in the `Zend\Feed` component with extensions. I have been messing around with it for a while.

**What happens?**

You construct a `Zend\Feed\Writer\Feed`. The `Feed` extends the `Zend\Feed\Writer\AbstractFeed`. In the `__construct()` of `AbstractFeed` happens this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    Writer::registerCoreExtensions();
    $this->_loadExtensions();
}
```

`Writer` is here the `Zend\Feed\Writer\Writer`. The `registerCoreExtensions` looks as follows:

```
public static function registerCoreExtensions()
{
    static::registerExtension('DublinCore');
    static::registerExtension('Content');
    static::registerExtension('Atom');
    static::registerExtension('Slash');
    static::registerExtension('WellFormedWeb');
    static::registerExtension('Threading');
    static::registerExtension('ITunes');
}
```

Here, you see the different extens are added to the static `Writer` instance. From there on, the `_loadExtensions()` call fetches all extensions registered from the `Writer` and imports them into the `Feed`. The same happens by the way in the `AbstractRenderer`.

**How to fix?**

Because internally inside the Feed and Renderer the `registerCoreExtensions()`  is called, you cannot overwrite the default list of extensions. Also, the Feed and the Renderer do not have getters/setters for the extension. The only way I came up with is to write your own Feed object and Renderer object.

For the *Feed* object you create a getter/setter to remove the extensions you want. You also override `export` where you copy the contents of the method, but overwrite the `$renderClass` variable name to the render class of your own.

For the *Renderer* class you create a getter/setter to remove the extensions you want as well. This way, you can tune the extensions you need. It's not that pretty, but hopefully it's something improved upon in ZF3 :)

Comment: I have also raised an issue regarding this for ZF3 on the Github repository: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6122